# How to return the index of the first Roman Numeral in a string

Tags: java

this is my first question, and I am very much a beginner in coding in Java, and I have a question about this topic.

If there is a string s, that contains a roman numeral (i, v, x, l, c, d, m), the job of the program is to return the index of the first occurring roman numeral... For example, a string named "civil" would return 0, because c is the first roman numeral and its index is 0.

I am familiar with string indexOf() method, and I've tried to make it like:

```
        int indexc = s.indexOf('c');
        int indexi = s.indexOf('i');
        int indexv = s.indexOf('v');
        int indexl = s.indexOf('l');
        int indexx = s.indexOf('x');
        int indexd = s.indexOf('d');
        int indexm = s.indexOf('m');
        if (indexc >= 0) {
            return indexc;
        } if (indexi >= 0) {
            return indexi;
        } if (indexv >= 0) {
            return indexv;
        } if (indexl >= 0) {
            return indexl;
        } if (indexx >= 0) {
            return indexx;
        } if (indexd >= 0) {
            return indexd;
        } if (indexm >= 0) {
            return indexm;
        } else {
           return -1;
        }
```

but I am not sure if this is what is supposed to happen. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done best with regex:

```
 Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[ivxlcdm]").matcher(s);
 int index = matcher.find() ? matcher.start() : -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

your answer is pretty complicated because of length and readability. Also, your answer will not be correct for strings that are not in the same order as you wrote for example "ic": your code will return "1" since your code first checks if there is a 'c' and returns the 'c' and does not check all the roman numerals simultaneously.

Therefore I wrote a different answer that should be a simple answer. This code segment checks for every index of the string if it is one of the wanted chars if so stop and return that index.

```
static int findRomanI(String s){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ;i++){
        if(s.charAt(i) == 'i' || 
            s.charAt(i) == 'v' ||
            s.charAt(i) == 'x' ||
            s.charAt(i) == 'l' || 
            s.charAt(i) == 'c' || 
            s.charAt(i) == 'd' || 
            s.charAt(i) == 'm')
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for every character and returning it in the order you want it to be returned, i.e. `c` first and `i` later, and so on.

You can do it this way:

```
public class IndexOfRomanChar {
    private static final char[] ROMAN_CHARS = {'i', 'v', 'x', 'l', 'c', 'd', 'm'};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = "civil";

        System.out.println(getIndexOfRomanChar(word));
    }

    private static int getIndexOfRomanChar(String word) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            for (char c : ROMAN_CHARS) {
                if (word.charAt(i) == c) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This code first iterates over each letter of the word and checks if it's contained in every item in `ROMAN_CHARS` which is the array where we define all the possible letters the program should look for.